# Docker from windows is unable to pull images from my private registry once Kubernetes is enabled

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-for-windows

I've installed Docker Desktop version 2.1.0.1 on my Windows 10 PRO laptop which has Hyper-V enabled.

Because of quite a few know issues of MiniKube with Windows 10, I'm using the kubernetes installation provided within the Docker Desktop application.

I've created a private repository on 10.1.1.101:5000. I've also added this IP to the list of insecure hosts.

Before I enabled kubernetes, I was able to push and pull images freely from my private registry. But once I started kubernetes, I've started getting an

> C:\Users\saurabh> docker pull 10.1.1.101:5000/busybox
>   Using default tag: latest
>   Error response from daemon: Get http://10.1.1.101:5000/v2/: dial tcp 10.1.1.101:5000: connect: no route to host

My system's IP address is on the same network: `10.1.1.115`

Any help here is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try to delete all unused Docker Networks:

```
docker network prune
```

then set `bip` in your `C:\ProgramData\Docker\config\daemon.json` to use the same subnet as your network see [this](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/custom-docker0/)

hope that will help you

Comment: I don't have this path `C:\ProgramData\config\daemon.json`. Instead there's a daemon .json file in `C:\Users\saurabh\.docker\daemon.json`. The contents of the file are as follows:

```
{
  "registry-mirrors": [],
  "insecure-registries": [
    "smsglobal.alan:5000",
    "10.1.1.131:5000"
  ],
  "debug": true,
  "experimental": false
}
```

Could the bip settings be added here?

Comment: Thanks for that mate... but when I added a bip parameter, my docker refused to start. Any idea why this would happen?